# C++ Copy Objects from a file to a Array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi need to copy the written objects in a file to copy to a array But following code gives me a Error

```
   T Obj
   T arr[20];
   while(file.read((char*)&Obj,sizeof(Obj))){
          int i=0;
             i++

            arr[i]==Obj;
            }
```

Error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type

Comment: Well for one thing, you have no semicolon after i++.

Comment: ... and i is local, so the code will always access arr[1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, firstly, the operator `==` is used for comparison, not assignment.  For assignment, you want a single `=`.  Secondly, your code is not portable, and possibly broken, because the way your object is stored on disk as a sequence of bytes is not necessarily the same way that it is stored in memory as a `T` object.  This is because different computers/platforms/compilers represent binary data in different ways.  Plus, as Vlad mentions in the comment below, if instances of `T` contain internal pointers, (like `std::string`), then your program will simply fall apart.

You should probably look into a **[serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)**, or at least use C++ iostreams to serialize your object into a text format, then use an `istream_iterator` to read them from disk.

Comment: ... and if the object contains pointers, this kind of deserialization is plainly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ '==' is the equality operator, if you want to assign the object to the array 'arr' you should use a single '='.
Also reading objects directly from a binary file is "questionable". You should use "stream operators" instead (Google it).